# Function that fit a cube to 8 selected vertices

Tags: python, objects, vertices

I'm trying to make a script that can create a cube where the vertices are moved to 8 selected vertices in the scene. I want this function because of my physic collision workflow later on in a game engine.

However this is easier said than done. Matching the order of the selected vertices to the outer bounds of the cube (so that the cube doesn't get deformed in a weird way) is not easy. Has someone done this kind of function before? Or does someone have a good solution that could work?

A cube has 8 vertices so if you want to span a cube to 8 vertices in a scene you need to have 8 different positions to span each vertex to.

[image: After running this script i get a cube, that span the selected vertices, the cube on the right is the result]

However if the indices are ordered in a weird way, this is not that easy, as you need to identify the bounds (top right forward corner for example of the selected vertices which the created cube top right forward corner should be positioned at.

This is the script that works for vertices that have normal index order.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import *
from math import *


obj=bpy.context.object

locations = []

if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    for v in bm.verts:  
        if v.select:
            location = v.co
            locations.append(Vector(location))

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    newObj = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(obj.location))   
    newObj = bpy.context.object
    newObj.scale = obj.scale


    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    bm2 = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(newObj.data)

    for i in range(0,len(locations)):
        print(bm2.verts[i].co)
        bm2.verts[i].co = locations[i]


else:
    print("Object is not in edit mode.")
```

this part:

```
for i in range(0,len(locations)):
            print(bm2.verts[i].co)
            bm2.verts[i].co = locations[i]
```

is wrong because it needs to be looking into each position and compare them to make the cube span the positions in a correct way. But this is the problem, how do i do this in a easy way?

Comment: 8 points is too many, do you also want the cube to rotate or not? Could you post a picture with example what you want?

Comment: I updated the question, maybe now it becomes clearer

Comment: Oh so the cube can be a block or totally distorted right? Ill look into it

Comment: Yes exactly, but I will only use it on block type of shapes, but yes :)

Thank you

Comment: If i were tackling this I'd start by writing a function to "score" quadruples of points as coplanar.  Then you have to pick which quads are most likely to be faces, probably by scoring how perpendicular they are to other faces.  Or maybe you just want to compute a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull .

Comment: Yeah you want the convex hull, that is the most robust method

Comment: Oh! Thank you. Blender has a built in one, the Convex Hull as you said. (I tried miserably to write an algorithm doing this by myself).
However is it possible to call this function from code instead of in the 3D view?